# Convert Excel sheet to paradox DB

Tags: excel, database, paradox

given a data in an excel sheet, For the purpose of converting it to Paradox DB, to get used in paradox program. there are any application that convert excel sheet to paradox DB?

Comment: Did you try [this](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enUA863UA863&biw=1858&bih=977&sxsrf=ALeKk00Q0kAltPJ6qzKtgBxrcltTWKPPEA%3A1582107195639&ei=OwpNXrTcJq6H1fAP0bqwyAI&q=import+from+excel+to+paradox+db+&oq=import+from+excel+to+paradox+db+&gs_l=psy-ab.3...94623.97811..97978...1.0..0.137.956.7j3......0....1j2..gws-wiz.......35i39j0i7i30j0i203j33i22i29i30.G2x-DAg7aN0&ved=0ahUKEwj05ZHLsN3nAhWuQxUIHVEdDCk4ChDh1QMICw&uact=5)?

Answer (score 0):

The paradox application itself can definitely import csv files and store them in a paradox table. I can’t remember if it can import Xls direct so you may have to save as in excel to convert your data to csv first.

Answer (score 0):

Save the excel file as `DBF` or `WK1` or `csv`, Import it in Paradox.